# How to take advantage of default top for absolutely positioned element

Tags: css, css-position

Just notice `position:absolute` element can be assigned a default `top` value based on position of its 'immediate parent' regardless `relative` or not. According to [BoltClock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033949/how-exactly-does-absolute-position-element-behaves-inside-a-static-parent/20034067#20034067),

> it remains in the static position and doesn't go anywhere.

Here is the code:

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.parent {
  height: 200px;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #a6cee3;
  border: 3px solid #1f78b4;
}

.green {
  background-color: #b2df8a;
  border: 3px solid #33a02c;
}

.red {
  background-color: #fb9a99;
  border: 3px solid #e31a1c;
}

.orange {
  background-color: #fdbf6f;
  border: 3px solid #ff7f00;
}

.violet {
  background-color: #cab2d6;
  border: 3px solid #6a3d9a;
}
```

```html
<div class="container blue">
  <div class="parent orange"></div>
  <div class="parent violet">
    <div class="child red"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the absolute element occupy the 'remaining space' of the container, i.e. excluding the first parent. My idea is to set `bottom:0`, what I expect is `top` is already set somehow, and if `bottom` is set as well, it can  height can be calculated and expand the remaining space, but this do not work out.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An absolutely positioned box may only take on the static position if both `top` and `bottom` (or both `left` and `right`, or all four) are auto. You cannot set an offset on one side and expect the box to remain in the static position, since once you offset a box *it is no longer in the static position*.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not set the `width` and `height` of your absolutely-positioned child element to `100%`?**

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaSpyder/u4dk5m08/3/) remix of your fiddle.

Comment: I want it to leave out the first parent, rather than cover the whole container

Comment: @Guigui I updated the fiddle. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I want the first parent (which is removed by you) to take place as well