# HTML/CSS How to create an overlay that covers a certain container without using "position:absolute;"?

Tags: html, css, layout, overlay

I need to create an overlay element with HTML/CSS that covers only a certain container, not the whole page. I could use `position:absolute;` and then everywhere 0px, but the trouble is that I cannot position the container that should be covered, it has to stay positioned static, and then `position:absolute;` will not relate to this container.

So I tried to fix this setting height and width to 100%:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#ovl {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a10000a1;
}
#container {
  border: 4px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="ovl">
                This Overlay should hide the images.
            </div>
            <img height=300 src="1.png" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
            <img height=300 src="2.png" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
            <img height=300 src="3.png" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I expected that the red overlay element would cover the whole container and the three images in it, but I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4g8vG.png). The three images (music scores) are not covered by the red overlay. Is there any error in my code? How to fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How exactly does absolute position element behaves inside a static parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033949/how-exactly-does-absolute-position-element-behaves-inside-a-static-parent)

Comment: So, the overlay is outside of the div that is nested?

Comment: display:grid could be used if you assign to the overlay the same area that image covers. see answer below.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Unfortenatly this did not solve my problem.

Comment: @AxelAnaya The overlay is inside the container div, but I could change this if necessary.

Comment: Is there any case where `position:relative;` without any `top:...` or `bottom:...` although changes the position of the element? If not, and I don't think so, I could use this for the container and then `position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; ...` for the overlay.

Comment: @ferdi2003 if you use `width` and  `height` at 100%, you remove the use of `top` and the others, and the overlay will overlap all the div

Comment: this is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MaddozS/pen/PMJByW) wtih using __grid__ and __position__

Answer (score 1):

CSS Grid can do that. No positioning required.

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#ovl {
  background-color: #a10000a1;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
}

#container {
  border: 4px dotted blue;
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}

img {
  grid-row: 1;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

img:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 1;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

img:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="ovl">
    This Overlay should hide the images.
  </div>
  <img height=300 src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
  <img height=300 src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
  <img height=300 src="http://www.fillmurray.com/g/140/100" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

### This is a solution using CSS Grid:

```css
.grid{
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
/*   grid-template-row: 1fr; */
  border: 3px dotted blue;
  width: 100%;
}
.overlay{
  background: #000000a1;
  color: white;
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 1/ span 3;
  z-index: 1;
}
.img1{
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 1/ span 1;
}
.img2{
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 2/ span 2;
}
.img3{
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-row: 3/ span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="overlay">
    This Overlay should hide the images.
  </div>
  <img src="1.png" class="img1" alt="Error!">
  <img src="2.png" class="img2" alt="Error!">
  <img src="3.png" class="img3" alt="Error!">
</div>
```

This is my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MaddozS/pen/PMJByW) if you want to try and experiment

Comment: Wasn't that you who answered I should use "position:relative;" for the container, but then deleted this answer? However, the reason why I wanted to omit using `position:absolute;` for the overlay was bacause I did not know how to position the container without changing its real position. But if `position:relative;` does not change the position if top/bottom/... are not specified, I can use this. Is there any case when relative positioning without any other specification changes the position?

Comment: Yes, I deleted my answer because that you said about avoiding the use of `position`, however, if you `relative` position a top/bottom..., 

`position: relative` will layout an element relative to itself. In other words, the elements is laid out in normal flow, then it is removed from normal flow and offset by whatever values you have specified

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css?rq=1)

Comment: Then it was my fault to write that I wish to avoid `position`. So it is a good solution for my problem to `position` the container `relative` and the overlay `absolute` and everywhere `0px`...? This will **definitely not** change the position of any element except the overlay?

Comment: If you want to overlay everything in your container you should use height and width at 100%, because when you use position absolute in a tag, it will ignore all the positions of its relatives. but keeping the positions of its first position relative parent, that's why you need to use position relative in the container

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do an overlay, is using `position:absolute` in the child and `position:relative` in the parent, this will be your CSS code

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#ovl {
  background-color: #a10000a1;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  border: 4px dotted blue;
  position: relative;
}
```

See the results [here](https://codepen.io/MaddozS/pen/PMJByW)

All the other solutions without positions absolute/relative could be very cumbersome

Comment: the op did not want to use absolute positioning, only grid can do this without it  :)

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding of the problem , There is an error with your Divs. try this instead:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
      <div id="ovl">
        <div id="container">

                This Overlay should hide the images.
            </div>
            <img height=300 src="1.png" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
            <img height=300 src="2.png" class="imgs" alt="Error!">
            <img height=300 src="3.png" class="imgs" alt="Error!">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#ovl {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a10000a1;
}
#container {
  border: 4px dotted blue;
}
```

Comment: Since you only exchanged the IDs, the code you wrote will cause the image container to be red and the overlay to have a blue border, which is not my intention. My intention was to make the overlay filling the whole container, see above.