# Default location of position absolute without top/bottom/left/right set

Tags: html, css

Since position absolute will remove the element from the document flow, I am expecting elements with position absolute without setting top/bottom/left/right in a same container will be put on the exact same location. But it turned out, it is not the case.

I am trying to simulate what I mean in here. Please run the code snippet to see what I mean.

```css
.first, .second, .third {
  width: 25%;
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.first {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.second {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.third {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 10%;
  height: 30px;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="absolute"></div>
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second"></div>
      <div class="absolute"></div>      
      <div class="third"></div>
      <div class="absolute" style="background-color: black; z-index:-1"></div>      

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It turned out that the second and third `.absolute` div is stacked together on the same location, and the first div right on top it. Change the z-index to prove it was stacked.

I read this post position: [absolute without setting top/left/bottom/right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243991/position-absolute-without-setting-top-left-bottom-right) but still it does not makes sense to me at least in my case.

Please clarify my understanding. Much appreciated.

Referring to this post, [What are the default top, left, botton or right values when position:absolute is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968979/what-are-the-default-top-left-botton-or-right-values-when-positionabsolute-is)

**EDIT**: It turned out that by not setting the top/bottom/left/right, it will set it automatically instead of zero. Zero would end up all these elements on the same location but not auto.But even it is auto, I don't understand how the second and third div ended up stacked together but not the first one? When the position is in static, it is three different locations. Having it top/bottom/left/right auto should put it in three different location as well supposedly

Comment: If you place all the `absolute` elements together, before the `inline-block` elements, you will get your desired result.

Comment: @sideroxylon: yes. But I need it to be on different location. Which I thought, should not cause any issues