# What happens with fixed position elements when I don't set a "left" or "right" property and is it dependable?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a sidebar sitting to the left of a text container, but I'm very unsure if my method is dependable across browsers!

Basically, I rely on a fixed positioned sidebar but avoiding to set `left` to anything so that it is contained within its parent.

Is this a default behaviour or something different browsers handle in their own little funny ways?

Example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7enadwus/

Example code:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Some text</p>
</div>

<div class="float">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <p>Sidebar</p>
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.float {
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: blue;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: u need with out float class right?

Comment: if margin is auto it will be in the center

Comment: check thi url https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @MohanSrinivas Sorry, I don't understand? The float class is just to get the sidebar to hang BESIDE the container, not mashed in it! It has a bigger width.

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar It doesn't have a margin though! :)

Comment: @AnzilkhaN What in that document do you want me to read? I can't find anything that helps me!

Comment: actually whats ur exact issue?u just added some css and div..based on that css, your side bar and container display

Comment: The sidebar div is under float div.float div is relative that's y the side bar position also changing automatically!

Comment: @Mohan Srinivas: The title is not difficult to understand. The asker just wants to know if it's OK not to set left or right when using fixed positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior covered in [section 10.3.7 of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968979/what-are-the-default-top-left-botton-or-right-values-when-positionabsolute-is/19969046#19969046). Fixed positioned elements count as absolutely positioned elements for the purposes of these sources. In short, `left` and `right` default to auto when not set, resulting in the fixed positioned element remaining in its static position (where it would have been had `position` not been set).

Yes, you can rely on this behavior being interoperable across all browsers.

Comment: I will accept this answer but I think you have some typo or something in your text. It doesn't shift to the far left of the browser viewport *unless* `left` is set!

Comment: @SophieD: Thanks for pointing that out, I must've been distracted.